# How to alter request handling?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Is it possible to alter request handling in Scrapy?
For example if I want that particular URL must be requested not by scrapys stanard machinery, but with Selenium, and make me able to operate with it with Selenium driver methods.

How to do that?

Comment: Have you read [Downloader Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#topics-downloader-middleware-setting)? If so, how is it not what you want, or where are you stuck? If not, why not go read it?

Comment: @abarnert Downloader middleware cant override how url is downloaded.

Comment: Yes it can. Read it again. Why do you think it's called **downloader** middleware? How do you think `HttpCacheMiddleware` could possibly work if it couldn't prevent the normal download from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to alter the request, you can simply execute Selenium within your spider.

```
def parse(self, response):
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    for i in response.xpath("//a/@href").extract():
        browser.get(i)
        #then do other stuff
```

But in my experience, there are very very very few things you cannot do with scrapy alone.
Do you have a link to show what kind of things you're looking for ?

Comment: Your code do unnecessary request, while I want to override the way how requests are handled.

Comment: Nope, nothing unnecessary here, each piece has its own purpose. If you want to handle requests with selenium, then use selenium, if you want to handle requests using scrapy then use scrapy. I don't see how it gets any easier than that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to write is a [downloader middleware component](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html). You ask if it's possible to "alter request handling"; its introduction says it's a "system for globally altering Scrapy’s requests and responses"; I don't know why you wouldn't think that's what you're looking for, but if you read on, it is exactly what it sounds like.

The key method in a `DownloaderMiddleware` object is `process_request`. As the docs say:

> This method is called for each request that goes through the download middleware.
>
> `process_request()` should either: `return None`, return a `Response` object, return a `Request` object, or raise `IgnoreRequest`.
>
> …
>
> If it returns a `Response` object, Scrapy won’t bother calling any other `process_request()` or `process_exception()` methods, or the appropriate download function; it’ll return that response.

So, you just write a `DownloaderMiddleware` whose `process_request` calls Selenium, processes what it gets back, and returns it wrapped in a `Response`.

The built-in `HttpCacheMiddleware` should demonstrate how to do this if it's not obvious.